# Format date field in Power BI service

Tags: powerbi

I have imported an Excel file to Power BI service from my OneDrive for Business.
The file contains a simple Excel table and one of the fields is a date.
Now, in Power BI service, I get that field displayed as a whole number which isn't very useful to read in a report.

How do I change the field to display as date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **FORMAT()** method to format date value, Use below mentioned formula

**Syntax:**    `Column = FORMAT(Table[column],"MM/DD/YYYY")`

```
Column = FORMAT(DailyActiveUsers[startDate],"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

**Before my data:**

[image]

**After my data:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This usually works by default for true Excel dates.  Anyway, just open the Edit Queries window and navigate to your table.  In the column header for your Date, change the Data type to Date.  Close & Apply to see the result in your report.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but in Power BI service there's no Edit Queries window (that's in desktop).

Comment: You are so right.  I would start building that report again in Power BI Desktop.  Building reports in the service seems like a risky dead-end.  Plus you have much less control as you have discovered.

Comment: If you need ex post modelling capabilities on an already imported Excel file, it usually helps to do the modelling in Excel with Power Query (either install as an add-in on older Excel versions; or use the integrated tool in the 2016 edition). Then you can shape the data within the excel file and have it properly formatted in your PowerBI service.

Comment: Actually Power Query is already embedded in Power BI Desktop - it's the Edit Queries window.